# AngularJS Unknow provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to set a new controller in my Angular app, but I have this error coming:

[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=successRedirectProvider%20%3C-%20successRedirect%20%3C-%20ingreCtrl.

I tried many things for a few hours but still have this issue.
Here's my files:

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['formSubmit']);
app.factory('successRedirect', function(){
return function(data) {

  if(data.status === "success") {
    alert(data.message);
    if (typeof(data.redirect) !== "undefined"){
      document.location.href = data.redirect;
    }
  }else{

  }

  };
});

app.factory('errors', function(){
return function(data) {

  alert(data.message)
  for(var i = 0; i<data.errors.length;i++){
    $('#new-page-form-container').append('<p>'+data.errors[i]+'</p>');
  }
     };
});
```

**formApp.js:**

```
var formSubmit = angular.module('formSubmit', ['ckeditor', 'ngFileUpload']);
```

**ingredientsCtrl.js:**

```
  formSubmit.controller('ingreCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http',  'successRedirect', 'errors', function ($scope, $filter, $http, successRedirect,   errors) {

}]);
```

Comment: Have you actually read the [URL the error is linking to](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=successRedirectProvider%20%3C-%20successRedirect%20%3C-%20ingreCtrl)?

Comment: @deceze that's for suckers!

Comment: @Pogrindis Pfff, I know, *right*. That's like sooo 1999.

Comment: For me the controller can t reach the successRedirect Factory but I can t understand why, or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: you injection wrong : 

**var app = angular.module('app', []);** and 

**var formSubmit = angular.module('formSubmit', ['app', 'ckeditor', 'ngFileUpload']);**

Comment: I tried that already, but not working.

Comment: What is your js files include order? Maybe it's your problem

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the `successRedirect` service **of the `app` module** inside your `formSubmit` module. That means you need to dependency inject `app` into `formSubmit`:

```
var formSubmit = angular.module('formSubmit', ['app', 'creditor', 'ngFileUpload']);
                                               ^^^^^
```

Not the other way around.

Comment: Tried, and still not working and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found why it doesn't work, last week I did another module for the login system in my web site in another file, and I didn't remember that I already gave the name 'app' to this module, so I change my module's name in the file app.js and it works.
But to answer to some comments, my dependency injection was good, as my inclusion, no need to change the order. The problem was the module name.
Thanks anyway for your time, subject close ^^